# Neo4j heap size

Tags: java, neo4j, heap-memory

When I run my java embedded Neo4j program with the same JVM parameters on two different linux servers, one with 24 cores and 64G RAM successfully does the job but the other gives me a heap size error although it has 768G RAM and 32 cores. Error happens at this line of the code:
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(PATH+GRAPH_DATABASE_PATH)
                    .setConfig( "keep_logical_logs","100M size").newGraphDatabase();

I set -Xmx4g in both runs. Could the error be somehow related to the number of users and the load on the second server, as many users share this machine? Here is the Error I receive:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.(MuninnPageCache.java:246)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.createPageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:94)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.getOrCreatePageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:85)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.PlatformModule.createPageCache(PlatformModule.java:279)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.PlatformModule.(PlatformModule.java:156)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.createPlatform(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:181)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:129)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:117)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:185)

Comment: Wow! You have access to that kind of servers! Why are you limiting the max heap that way to 4G only? Why don't you start your app like: `java -server -Xmx64G -jar myapp.jar`?

Comment: Hi, because I want to show my program is memory-efficient compared to the other similar tools. So I set these parameters: java -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -Xmx4g  -jar ... Actually the first run even works with -Xmx2g!

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just configure the page-cache size explicitly:

```
dbms.pagecache.memory=5G
```

depending on you storage size on disk.